# Add A Context Manager To A Single View Application

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8, appdelegate

When I create a single view application in Xcode it starts of with a ViewController class that loads with the viewDidLoad function.

I've done some research but can't quite seem to figure out how to change the default load behaviour of this.

What I would like to do is:
Have a class called ContextManager that is opened first. 
This context manager then calls whatever ViewController class I would like.

I believe I need to work with this delegate in the AppDelegate.swift:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

What I don't get is how the initial ViewController class is even being called or opened, I don't see the delegate calling it.

If you can advise how I can intercept this load event and instead have my ContextManager be the first class called that would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create your main window and initial view controller manually instead of letting `UIApplicationMain` do it.

First, select your target and clear out the main interface.  This prevents `UIApplicationMain` from trying to set up your window and initial view controller:

[image: clearing out main interface]

Then, in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, create the window manually, and load your view controller of choice from the storyboard.  For example, here I choose randomly between view controllers with storyboard IDs of “1” and “2”:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let choice = "\(arc4random_uniform(2) + 1)"
    window?.rootViewController =
        storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(choice) as? UIViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Love the gif. Epic answer, much appreciated thank you!